# How to display the toast

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase and react native to create an app and have created the following funcs in

```
//auth.js
export const signUpWithEmailAndPassword = async (
  email,
  password,
  navigation
) => {
  try {
    const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      email,
      password
    );
    const user = userCredential.user;
    navigation.navigate("SignIn");
  } catch (error) {
    //display toast
    return false;
  }
};

export const signInWithEmailzAndPassword = async (
  email,
  password,
  navigation
) => {
  try {
    const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      email,
      password
    );
    const user = userCredential.user;
    navigation.navigate("Home");
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
};
```

AND using these in signIn.jsx

```
//signIn.jsx
const signMeIn = async () => {
    signInWithEmailzAndPassword(text.email, text.password, navigation);
  };
  const signMeUp = () => {
    try {
      signUpWithEmailAndPassword(text.email, text.password, navigation);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

here is my custom toast displaying func

```
//toast.js
export const showCustomToast = (
  message,
  type = "info",
  duration = 4000,
  backgroundColor = "blue",
  textColor = "white"
) => {
  ToastAndroid.show({
    type: type,
    text1: message,
    position: "bottom",
    visibilityTime: duration,
    autoHide: true,
    topOffset: 30,
    bottomOffset: 40,
    customStyles: {
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      color: textColor,
    },
  });
};
```

Now I want to display a toast on success or failure with the error message but encountering a problem and these were the method tried by me

1. Tried using try-catch in SignIn.jsx -If there was an error is signIn
   func in auth.js the error was only consoled there the code never
   enters catch block in signIn.js
2. Tried passing a errorHandler func in auth.js signIn func-It causes
   an error com.facebook.react.bridge.readablenativemap cannot be cast
   to java.lang.string
   can Someone tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **react-hot-toaster**:
https://react-hot-toast.com/docs/use-toaster

The best toaster in react. It will automatically do everything for you. You just need to call
Nore :- See usage with react Native for yourself.